# Could not load file or assembly 'Magick.NET-Q16.Wrapper-x64.dll'

Tags: c#, .net, dll, imagemagick

I see a lot of similar questions out there about this wrapper or variations of this wrapper, but they were very old references and not applicable to my environment or made reference to DLLs that have changed or don't exist any longer.

This is an app running IIS7 on a WinServer 2012R2. 
The problem doesn't always occur so very difficult to troubleshoot. I do have 5 Magick DLLs in the bin of my web app. I am wondering if I have an extra DLL or two that is getting called by accident??

- Magick.NET.Core.dll       v7.0.0.15
- Magick.NET-AnyCPU.dll     v7.0.0.15
- Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU.dll v7.11.0.0
- Magick.NET-Q16-x64.dll    v7.11.0.0
- Magick.NET-Q16-x64.Native.dll v7.11.0.0

I am not calling these DLLS directly but they are used by another component that I am accessing. The problem only seems to occur on our production server or at least I have never been able to recreate it on our development server.
Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated.

The exact error from the Event Logs:

> An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.
>
> Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/EMedia
>
> Process ID: 1396
>
> Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>
> Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Magick.NET-Q16.Wrapper-x64.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
>
> StackTrace:    at ImageMagick.MagickImage.DisposeInstance()
>      at ImageMagick.MagickImage.Finalize()
>   Application: w3wp.exe
>
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>
> Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>      at ImageMagick.MagickImage.DisposeInstance()
>      at ImageMagick.MagickImage.Finalize()
>
> Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215df96
>
> Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.19269, time stamp: 0x5c5e079f
>
> Exception code: 0xe0434352
>
> Fault offset: 0x0000000000008e6c
>
> Faulting process id: 0x574
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d4cad8583d1700
>
> Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
>
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
>
> Report Id: 9bbdf82f-36cb-11e9-80e2-005056b051bb
>
> Faulting package full name:
>
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: Probably should as at https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET